# How to group a table and print a column which is not a function of column we are grouping on

Tags: sql, group-by, hiveql

I have a table, let us say as follows:

```
A     |    B    |     C
a1    |    b1   |     c1
a2    |    b2   |     c2
a3    |    b3   |     c3
a4    |    b4   |     c4
```

Here a1,a2,a3 need not be distinct, same for b and c. There aren't just 3 rows, there are millions, and I can't either select * from this table or create a temporary table.

The problem is to group by column A (so we want 1 row per distinct entry of this column), and print lots of aggregate data, but column C isn't a function of column A. There are just 3 distinct of entries in column C, and I have an ordering in them (say Michael > Rosen > John). I want every distinct entry in A to print the maximum of what it corresponds to.

For example, say a1 = 1, a2 = 1 and c1 = Michael, c2 = Rosen. I want to print Michael in the output in the row corresponding to 1 (and I want exactly one row per distinct entry in column A, that's why I am grouping by it).

I tried to use partition by clause along with group by, but then I couldn't accomplish it. Please help!

Comment: I have seen lots of posts which want to print maximum value partitioned by another field, but in this case the ordering in that field is also defined by us.

Comment: How many options are there for C, and what are the rules for the `ORDER BY`?

Comment: @DerrickMoeller, There are 3 options for column C, and the ordering is predecided by us, say Michael > Rosen > John, where the 3 distinct entries in column C are Michael, Rosen and John.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with `hiveql` but in `mssql` you could combine `ROW_NUMBER` with `LEN`, given that Michael, Rosen, and John can be sorted by length to get your desired `ORDER BY`.

```
SELECT yt.A, yt.C
FROM (SELECT A, C, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY A ORDER BY LEN(C) DESC) rn
      FROM yourtable) yt
WHERE yt.rn = 1
```

If you were providing sample data and being able to sort by `LEN` was just a coincidence, you could also use `CASE` if your use case is more complex.

```
SELECT yt.A, yt.C
FROM (SELECT A, C, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY A ORDER BY CASE WHEN C = 'Michael' THEN 1 WHEN C = 'Rosen' THEN 2 WHEN C = 'John' THEN 3 END ASC) rn
      FROM yourtable) yt
WHERE yt.rn = 1
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Yes it was just a coincidence, I've to use CASE. As I've written in the question, I want to calculate several other aggregate statistics also, and one row per entry of A is desired. Wouldn't it just sum over all the entries of B where C is Michael and A is 1 if I add group by yt.A here, instead of summing over all entries with A=1?

Comment: @Martund If your actual requirements are more complicated then what you've shared so far. You're likely going to have to modify your question with sample data and an expected output if you want to get any assistance.